# Open JFrame if JMenu is pressed? (Not JMenuItem)

Tags: java, swing, jmenu

Currently have a JMenu called menuAddGame, which is suppose to open a JFrame. However, I'm not too sure if this is possible. I currently have actionListeners for JMenuItems in a JMenu called menuGame.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        JMenuItem menuItem = (JMenuItem)e.getSource();


        System.out.println(menuItem.getText());
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Du valgte spillet: " + menuItem.getText());
        tempGamemode = menuItem.getText();
        showGameMode.setText(menuItem.getText());
        dd.setGameMode(menuItem.getText());
        dd.setGameMode(tempScore);
        question.setText(dd.getQuestion());



    }
    };
        dd.addGameMenu(menuGame, al);

    }
```

addGameMenu(JMenu, ActionListener) consists of:

```
public void addGameMenu(JMenu control, ActionListener al) {
        String fileName = "gamemodes.txt";
        try {

            FileReader inputFile = new FileReader(fileName);

            BufferedReader bufferReader = new BufferedReader(inputFile);

            String line;

            while ((line = bufferReader.readLine()) != null) {

                String split[] = line.split("#");
                for (int i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
                    JMenuItem menuItem = new JMenuItem(split[i]);
                    menuItem.addActionListener(al);
                    control.add(menuItem);
                }

            }

            bufferReader.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Fejl ved linje:" + e.getMessage());
        }

    }
```

How can I add a additional actionlistener, however, to the JMenu called menuAddGame?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I see this getting asked from time and it makes me cringe, this is not how `JMenu` was designed nor is it it's intention, `JMenu` is a container for `JMenuItem`s. If you want something similar, then I'd suggest using a `JToolBar` instead

Comment: I may be misinterrupting your question, I "think" you want to add more menu items to the `JMenu`?  I'd highly recommend having a look at [How to Use Actions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) as it could greatly reduce your work load

Comment: Oh damn, sorry brother, never knew of JToolBar. Got it fixed now, but thanks for the recommendation!